# Compare two JSON Files and Return the Difference

Tags: python, json, file, comparison

I have found some similar questions to this. The problem is that none of those solutions work for me and some are too advanced. I'm trying to read the two JSON files and return the difference between them.

I want to be able to return the missing object from file2 and write it into file1.

These are both the JSON files

```
file1

[
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "USA"
 }
]
```

.

```
file2

[
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Oscar Bernard",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "Australia"
 }
]
```

The code

```
with open("file1.json", "r") as f1:
    file1 = f1.read()
    item1 = json.loads(file1)
    print(item1)

with open("file2.json", "r") as f2:
    file2 = f2.read()
    item2 = json.loads(file2)
    print(item2)

# Returns if that index is the same
for v in range(len(item1)):
    for m in range(len(item2)):
        if item2[v]["name"] == item1[m]["name"]:
            print("Equal")
        else:
            print("Not Equal")
```

I'm not used to programming using JSON or comparing two different files.
I would like help to return the difference and basically copy and paste
the missing object into file1. What I have here shows me if each object in file1
is equal or not to file2. Thus, returning the "Equal" and "Not Equal" output.

Output:

```
Equal
Not Equal
Not Equal
Not Equal
Equal
Not Equal
```

I want to return if file1 is not equal to file2 and which object ("name")
is the one missing. Afterward, I want to be able to add/copy that missing object into file2 using with open("file2.json", "w").

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What will you do if the difference between the two files is more complex than that?

Comment: I did think of that question. That's why I'm trying to work with these simple JSON files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open("file1.json", "r") as f1:
    file1 = json.loads(f1.read())
with open("file2.json", "r") as f2:
    file2 = json.loads(f2.read())

for item in file2:
    if item not in file1:
        print(f"Found difference: {item}")
        file1.append(item)

print(f"New file1: {file1}")
```

Comment: I did not thought it was that simple. I kind of made it a bit too complicated with my code, but I did not know about the 'f' in print. Thank you!

Comment: How would I return the difference only by using a key, such as "name"?
I tried doing *if item['name'] not in file1:*
That didn't work and just return all of the names from file2

Comment: for item in [x['name'] for x in file2]:
    if item not in [x['name'] for x in file1]:
        print(f"Found difference: {item}")
        file1.append(item)

Comment: That returns the error: *TypeError: string indices must be integers*

Answer (score 1):

```
file1=[
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "USA"
 }
]
file2=[
 {
    "name": "John Wood",
    "age": 35,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Mark Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "USA"
 },
 {
    "name": "Oscar Bernard",
    "age": 25,
    "country": "Australia"
 }
]

for item in file2:
    if item['name'] not in [x['name'] for x in file1]:
        print(f"Found difference: {item}")
        file1.append(item)

print(f"New file1: {file1}")
```